# how to determine the data type of reserved identifier in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, reserved-words

I am rather new to using some advanced concepts in C. I am trying to understand the code from an API that uses `_`, `>>` and `<<`. I understand `_` is used as a reserved identifier, `>>` is used for a bitwise right, and `<<` is used for a bitwise left shift.

But what I am wondering is how do we know what data type argument does `OFFSET_AND_ROUND2` accepts? and how and why the function does the bitwise operation for offset and rounding?. Lastly, why I am getting the error invalid operands?

Please find the code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(_a, _b) (((_a)+(1<<((_b)-1))-((_a)<0?1:0))>>(_b))

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n\n");
    printf("%d", OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(3.87,2));
    return 0;
}
```

Please find the error message below:

```
main.c:10:69: error: invalid operands to binary >> (have 'double' and 'int')


#define OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(_a, _b) (((_a)+(1<<((_b)-1))-((_a)<0?1:0))>>(_b))
                                                                     ^
main.c:15:18: note: in expansion of macro 'OFFSET_AND_ROUND2'
     printf("%d", OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(3.87,2));
                  ^
```

I look forward to learning a little more about C, thanks!

Comment: The error message is clear: you cannot shift floating point values.

Comment: The `_` doesn't matter here, those restrictions are not applied to macro parameters (if I remember correctly). *"what data type argument"* You don't know, it's just a dumb text substitution.

Comment: you have just discovered one major reason why macros suck, you cannot specify type information. Sadly bit twiddlers long ago adopted this as the standard practice for their tricks.

Comment: "how do we know what data type argument does OFFSET_AND_ROUND2 accepts?" --> In this case, `_a` gets the type of `3.87`, which is `double` and `_b` gets the type of `2`, which is `int`.  With `OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(2. 3.87)` it would be the other way around and also a compiler problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using macros the preprocesser takes the content of the macro and replaces each occurence.
As an example:

```
#define A 5
...
int a = A;
```

gets translated to

```
int a = 5;
```

The same is for parameters:

```
#define A(_a) (_a+1)
...
int a = A(2);
```

gets translated to

```
int a = (2+1);
```

In the end it doesn't matter which data types are used as long they support all needed operations.
The error is because you can't shift floats/doubles in c++

Because it works like search & replace it is pretty important to use brackets if necessary:

```
#define ADD(_a,_b) _a+_b
...
int a = ADD(5,4) * 3;
```

gets translated to

```
int a = 5+4 * 3 // = 5 + (4 * 3) = 17
```

while (5+4)*3 = 27

Comment: thanks for the explanation, do you know what exactly does OFFSET_AND_ROUND2 does?

Comment: It shift `_a` by `_b` bits to the left but rounds up instead of down: `11 >> 1 = 5` because it is rounded down. `OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(11,1) = 6` becasue it gets rounded up. If you want to know exactly how it works I would recommend to calculate the function per hand.

Answer (score 3):

> But what I am wondering is how do we know what data type argument does *OFFSET_AND_ROUND2* accepts?

And that's one of the problems of macros. If there is no documentation
explicitly telling you the input and output data types, then you **have** to
look at how the macro was declared. Depending on your knowledge of C and on the
complexity of the macro, this can be hard to guess. That's one the reason most
experienced users tell to least experienced users "don't user macros".

In this case the macro is doing bit manipulation and addition and subtraction.
The result type will depend on the the type of the inputs. In case of `int`
inputs, the result will be an `int`.

About the error:

```
main.c:10:69: error: invalid operands to binary >> (have 'double' and 'int')
```

Here gcc is telling you that you've passed a `double` for the binary right shift `>>`-operator.
You can do right shift and left shift only with integer types (`char`, `int`,
`long`, etc.). Floating points (`float`, `double`) are not allowed on either
side of the operator.

So a correct call would be

```
printf("%d", OFFSET_AND_ROUND2(3,2));
```

If you don't know what shift is, the left shift moves the bit pattern to the
left, filling the "new" bits with 0. The right shift does the same but from the
right. Let say you have a byte with value `0x13` (19 in decimal)

The operation `char x = 0x13; char y = x << 2` will shift the bits of the
variable too times to the left, the result will be stored in `y`.

```
  msb = most significant bit
  lsb = least significant bit

  msb                             lsb
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |    == 19 (decimal)
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

  x << 2

  msb                             lsb
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
  | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |    == 76 (decimal)
  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```